# Prime number checker?

Tags: visual-c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a program that will check if a given number (between 1 and 1000) is prime but ran across a problem or two.  The code I have below will run, but output 1000 times because of line 14 (for(int i = 3; i <= ELEMENTS; i++){)  I know why it's running 1000 times but I can't find a way around it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "enter number of interest: ";
  int num;
    cin >> num;


const int ELEMENTS =1000;

bool multiples[ELEMENTS] = {};  

for(int i = 3; i <= ELEMENTS; i++){

  for(int j = 2; j <= i - 1; j++){
      multiples[i]=true;
    if(i % j == 0){
      multiples[j]=false;

    }
  }
  if((multiples[num] == true)){
    cout << num << " is prime" << endl;
  }
  else
  cout <<num<< " is not prime"<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember to mark answers as problem-solving using that big tick mark.

Answer (score 2):

Move it out of `for` loop. Since variables it uses are defined out of for loop scope, it will work fine.

**Edit:** correct fragment:

```
for(int i = 3; i <= ELEMENTS; i++){
  for(int j = 2; j <= i - 1; j++){
    multiples[i]=true;
    if(i % j == 0){
      multiples[j]=false;
    }
  }
}
if (multiples[num] == true) {
  cout << num << " is prime" << endl;
}
else
  cout << num << " is not prime" << endl;
```

Comment: What should I move out of the for loop?

Comment: @user3238772 The `if`-`else` block with the print statements.

Comment: I've added fixed sample

Comment: Thanks, that problem is solved.  However, now most of the prime numbers I input the compiler says that they're not prime :/